# Custom top row for gridview

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I am trying to make a gridview that has a different first row than the other rows. I used the following code to achieve what you can see in the screenshot. The only problem now is that when you scroll the top row stays there:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstImages"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageFirst"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageSecond"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageThird"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/catchesGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstImages"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dealersFooter"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        </GridView>
```

I am showing the images using Picasso:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = new SquaredImageView(context);
        view.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP);
    }

    Catch catchItem = getItem(position);

    String url = "image_url";

    Picasso.with(context) //
            .load(url) //
            .fit() //
            .into(view);

    return view;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `HeaderView` to `GridView` as First Row.

Comment: can you post the full XML file? I have a feeling it's because you're just scrolling just the gridLayout

Comment: You can't add a `HeaderView` to a `GridView`

Comment: @KevCron That is the problem. I am only scrolling the gridlayout. But how can I achieve that I can scroll everything at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstImages"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageFirst"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageSecond"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageThird"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/catchesGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstImages"
                android:layout_above="@+id/dealersFooter"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            </GridView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Now in your code, scroll using the `ScrollView` do not scroll using the GridView.

Also note that `ScrollView` can only host one direct child, hence the extra `LinearLayout`.

Comment: You only can scroll about 1 cm up now

Comment: When I use this gridview it works: http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/04/how-to-make-the-height-of-a-gridview-wrap-its-content/ Thanks a lot!